# Error: EMFILE: too many open files on win

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, electron

I was building an Vscode-like App, and I wrote my own extension to Vscode and put it into source code, it's work fine. But after I use gulp command to package my app, here is sth wrong :(On mac OS it's worked)

```
[17:07:59] Finished 'optimize-vscode' after 23 s
[17:07:59] Starting 'vscode-win32-x64'...
[17:08:31] Downloading extension: ms-vscode.node-debug2@1.25.6 ...
[17:08:32] Downloading extension: ms-vscode.node-debug@1.25.4 ...

events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'C:\Gitlab-Runner\builds\251c7da1\0\Haochen_super\IDE\extensions\hap-transformer\node_modules\qa-transformer\build\core\transformers\style\rules\declaration\dimension.js'
```

Can some one help me out on windows with this problem????

Comment: It looks like you actually have too many open files on that box. Have you tried looking at the number of open files with Process Monitor? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: I used Process explorer instead, and figure out the the node.js under the hood open more than 6000 files simultaneously. And thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure is this is the same problem or not, if it's - up vote my answer, if not - just continue to search.

When debugging with visual studio or visual code - visual studio keep logs of debugging session in file `%TEMP%\vscode-node-debug2.txt`.

It's indeed long log text, which is difficult to read and moreover understand what went wrong. But in my case I've found following log entry (somewhere close to the end of log):

```
â† From target: {"method":"Runtime.consoleAPICalled","params":{"type":"error","args":[{"type":"string","value":"WebpackO
ptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does
not match the API schema.\n - configuration.context: The provided value \"D:\\\\!deleteme!\\\\VuejsApp1\\\\VuejsApp1\" co
ntains exclamation mark (!) which is not allowed because it's reserved for loader syntax.\n   -\u003E The base directory
```

There were also a lot of `EMFILE` log entries, but they were not a root cause of failure.

Root cause in my case was that I have used special character in path - `D:\!deleteme!\VueJsApp` - and I have fixed it by simply creating directory without exclamation mark.

I was still not being able to debug VueJsApp - I suspect due to .vue to .js conversions, but normal javascript was possible to debug still.